# Serializer a input data with list [Django restframework]

Tags: django

I have a question with to declare an input data

```
{

  “id”: 1235,
  “products”:[
      { “product_id”: 1,      “descriptions”: “b” },
      { “product_id”: 2,     “descriptions”: “a” },     
      { “product_id”: 3,      “descriptions”: “c” }
    ]
}
```

So I have make the serializer like this

```
id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=true)
product_id= serializers.Integer()(required=False)
descriptions = serializers.CharField(max_lenght=300)<br>
products = [serializer.JSONField()]
```

Is it correct for it ? Thank you everyone

How get the django serializer for the list of a data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create 2 serializer class that the first one is for serializing single product and related fields:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    product_id= serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    descriptions = serializers.CharField(max_lenght=300)
```

the result is something like this:

```
{ “product_id”: 1,   “descriptions”: “b” }
```

your other serializer is a listSerializer of the above data that every single one is a child of this list:

```
class ListProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    products = serializers.ListField(child="childs of this list")
```

```
{
  “products”: []
}
```

The final result:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    product_id= serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    descriptions = serializers.CharField(max_lenght=300)


class ListProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    products = serializers.ListField(child=ProductSerializer())
```

```
{
  “products”:[
      { “product_id”: 1,   “descriptions”: “b” },
      { “product_id”: 2,   “descriptions”: “a” }    
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Tohid, could you explain more for this. as there is products contains product_ids and descriptions

Comment: tohid can you please add more detail that will justify your answer