# How to validate JSON using serializers with rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble figuring out how to serialize a list of int, string, and bool values using rest framework.
Imagine this JSON :

```
{
    "start_hour": "14:02:26",
    "DEVICE_INFO": [
        "0101",
        13
    ]
}
```

I have tried `ListSerializer()`, `ListField()`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class SensairValidateFormSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_hour = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    device_info = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ListSerializer([
            serializers.CharField(required=True),
            serializers.BooleanField(required=True),
        ]),
        required=False
    )
```

Comment: You must share the code, otherwise, how can we know what you have done? or suggest a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any examples, you can edit your post and share what you have done so far to address the issue you are facing.

Comment: checkout this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729899/serializer-a-input-data-with-list-django-restframework/75730095#75730095)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try utilizing `SerializerMethodField()`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class SensairValidateFormSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_hour = serializers.TimeField(format='%H:%M:%S', required=True)
    device_info = serilaizers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_device_info(self, obj):
        # handle the object as you see fit here
```

I also defined `start_hour` as a TimeField to ensure that the input string is formatted as a time. The format attribute is set to `%H:%M:%S` to match the format of the input string.

Comment: I tried your solution also, it doesn't work but it seems to be the correct one following the documentation... I changed my strategy, i use jsonschema and it works very well. Thanks @Ahmad.